# Text editor on WP caption

Tags: captions

I'm trying to add the visual editor to image captions in wordpress. I'm somewhat able to but there are a few issues.

Here is a screenshot of what I currently have:
[a busy cat http://www.pba-online.net/001.jpg](http://www.pba-online.net/001.jpg)

You can see "Visual" and "Text" there but no text editor buttons and the font is white.

I edited a core template file, which I know is not advisable but in this case, necessary:

the original code was :

```
<textarea {{ maybeReadOnly }}>{{ data.caption }}</textarea>
```

and I replaced it with

```
$settings = array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'wpautop' => true );
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
```

The issue are:
 - no text editor buttons
 - caption text is white
 - when saved, it does not show the caption

On the post page and when I click edit on the image, the caption is there as you can see in the image below:

[a busy cat http://www.pba-online.net/002.jpg](http://www.pba-online.net/002.jpg)

I'm looking at solving the 3 issues I have.

Thanks!

Comment: I've seen your question on here for some time now and it appears that what you are trying to do would result in an incorrect use of an image caption (<figcaption>). Why do you want to use a visual editor for image captions? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your linked image returns "404 Page Not Found!" Would be good to amend or remove the link.